# Error when building and debugging project in Visual Studio: Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set from other instances

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am working on my project in Visual Studio 2013, and vb.net. Everything is fine until today. My computer auto updated itself yesterday and I got this error when I try to debug my project today.

```
Error   1   The "ResolveComReference" task could not be instantiated from "Microsoft.    
Build.Tasks.v12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". 
Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set from other instances. (Exception 
from HRESULT: 0x80131401)   Proj1
```

Does anyone know what is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: see if the suggestions here help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168465/loading-this-assembly-would-produce-a-different-grant-set-from-other-instances

Comment: I tried to fix this problem by myself this afternoon. Here is what I did: 
I used the repair function to(basically reinstalled) fix visual studio. I believe the problem was that the building environment was changed in visual studio the targeting net framework was  changed as well ( because when I reopen my project, my project was re-targeted automatically to framework 4.5, which was updated to. ) So after I repaired visual studio 2013, I reopened my project. Then I change the targeted frame to my frame 3.5 that has my references built in before build the solution. Then  I re-added all the ref.

Comment: However< I still don't know what was actually causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. Following are the steps which sorted my issue:

1. In Website web config file Changed identity impersonate="true" to
   identity impersonate="False"
2. rebuild it & again changed it to identity impersonate="False"
   to identity impersonate="True"
3. Closed the application.
4. Delete temporary Internet files(V4.0.0.0 as I was using VS 2010).
5. Restarted IIS.
6. Opened Application & rebuild it.
7. Build Succeeded.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check the project references if all exists for the correct version