# IL Rewrite fails to load .Net DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, clr-profiling-api

I have built the IL Rewriter for some custom requirement. All it does is

1. Creates method references for another .Net DLL (newly built custom DLL)
2. Inject epilogue & prologue for few required methods, they internally call above method references.

Everything works fine with sample Windows form application. However, for the web application, epilogue & prologue are getting injected properly. But, when it gets called, it throws below error -

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Loading this assembly would produce a
>   different grant set from other instances. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131401)

Somehow, the newly built .Net DLL is not getting loaded for WebApp, while the same is working fine for Windows App.

If I disable IL Rewrite, everything works fine as expected. That means IL Rewrite is causing the error.

Any solution would be much appreciated

Comment: Did you try to google for error itself? E.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18168465/1997232) is a question.

Comment: Yes, I have done, but no luck. That is the reason, I have explained my scenario here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could resolve the issue by setting environment variable

```
COMPLUS_LoaderOptimization
```

to

```
1
```

Comment: I didn't understand the reason. I have tried multiple times, removing the above environment variable and adding back. It works only if the environment variable is present.

Comment: Are you using this in production code? Having the flag turned on can cause severe slow-down and increase in memory usage.

Comment: Yes, I read the documentation. But, I think, it will have a bad impact in case of multi-AppDomain within a process (w3wp). Otherwise, do you suggest any other better solution?